# Java sorts both integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I do not understand why `arrSort` gets sorted too even if I did not declare it to be sorted?

`arrSort1 = arrSort` does not mean `arrSort = arrSort1` right?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arrSort = {4024, 4209, 9254, 8996, 9017, 6679, 3412, 6546, 2682, 42};
    int[] arrSort1 = arrSort;
    displayArray(arrSort);
    displaySorted(arrSort1);
    displayArray(arrSort);
}
public static void displayArray(int[] arrList){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrList.length; i++)
        System.out.print(arrList[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
public static void displaySorted(int[] arrSort1){
    Arrays.sort(arrSort1);
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSort1.length; i++){
        System.out.print(arrSort1[i] + " ");    
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output says

```
4024 4209 9254 8996 9017 6679 3412 6546 2682 42 
42 2682 3412 4024 4209 6546 6679 8996 9017 9254 
42 2682 3412 4024 4209 6546 6679 8996 9017 9254
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same with pointer in C++, You are assign `arrSort1 = arrSort` then they are point to the same place in memory. When you do some thing with one then the other will change too. You may try to new it before assign

Answer (score 1):

Both `arrSort1`  and `arrSort` are referencing the same array hence the outcome, you might want to use [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)).

Example:

```
int[] arrSort1 = Arrays.copyOf(arrSort,arrSort.length);
```